# Element not displaying next to text HTML/CSS

Tags: html, css

So this is the code I'm working on:

**HTML**

```
<div id="t_welcomesection">
     <h1>Hello World!</h1>

    <p>Lorem Ipsum.
        <div class="morebtn"><a href="about.html">More >></a>
        </div>
    </p>
</div>
<!-- end of welcomesection -->
```

**CSS**

```
.morebtn {
color: #FFF;
background-color: rgba(219,87,5,1);
font-size: 17px;
-webkit-border-radius: 8px;
-moz-border-radius: 8px;
border-radius: 8px;
-webkit-box-shadow: 0px 9px 0px rgba(219,31,5,1), 0px 9px 25px rgba(0,0,0,.7);
-moz-box-shadow: 0px 9px 0px rgba(219,31,5,1), 0px 9px 25px rgba(0,0,0,.7);
box-shadow: 0px 9px 0px rgba(219,31,5,1), 0px 9px 25px rgba(0,0,0,.7);
width: 100px;
text-align: center;

-webkit-transition: all .1s ease;
-moz-transition: all .1s ease;
-ms-transition: all .1s ease;
-o-transition: all .1s ease;
transition: all .1s ease;
}

.morebtn:active {
color: #FFF;
-webkit-box-shadow: 0px 3px 0px rgba(219,31,5,1), 0px 3px 6px rgba(0,0,0,.9);
-moz-box-shadow: 0px 3px 0px rgba(219,31,5,1), 0px 3px 6px rgba(0,0,0,.9);
box-shadow: 0px 3px 0px rgba(219,31,5,1), 0px 3px 6px rgba(0,0,0,.9);
}

#t_welcomesection {

float: left;

width: 800px;

text-align: justify;

padding: 0px 50px 30px 50px;

}
```

See working sample [here](http://jsfiddle.net/NRjjM/)

I want the button to be next to the text. I don't know what's wrong with the code I have. Help is much appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: the problem is you don't put div tags in a paragraph.. it's not valid HTML

Comment: Use this `More >>` by `ampersands` and not literal symbols within the tag.

Comment: @Mr.Alien - For instance, `More &gt;&gt;`

Comment: click on the `?` - ?? - @Mr.Alien

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot have `div` nested inside a `p` tag as `p` can only hold `inline` elements, make your `div` a `span` and assign `display: inline-block;` to the `span` element

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/NRjjM/3/)

Comment: @neknekmouh make sure you use `display: inline-block;` so that it behaves like a block level element which is `inline`

Comment: @neknekmouh obviously it will :) also take a look what Nathan told you

Answer (score 2):

```
#t_welcomesection p {
display: inline-block;
}
.morebtn {
display: inline-block;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You've got `div` (a block element) inside a `p`. Just use span instead of div:
[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/NRjjM/2/)

Comment: thanks this works but the width is not reflecting in the span tag